# multiple cron jobs on the same postgres table

Tags: postgresql, cron, locking

I have a cron job that runs every 2 mins it takes a 10 records from a postgres table and working on them then it set a flag when it is finished. i want to make sure if the fist cron runs and takes more than 2 min the other one will run on different data on DBs not on the same data.

is there any why to handle this case?

Comment: no am not using any queuing system as beanstalkd, if i use them how can this case will be solved

Comment: Simplest way is to use a stamp/lock file on the filesystem. ( Both processes should obey and respect this lockfile)

Comment: @ruba I solved this using a Postgres Transaction. SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.colum = '1'; FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED after this.. do a BEGIN; UPDATE table SET value = '2'; COMMIT;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turn your "finished" flag from binary to ternary ("needs work", "in process", "finished").  You also might want to store the pid of the "in process" process, in case it dies and you need to clean it up, and a timestamp for when it started.

Or use a queueing system that someone already wrote and debugged for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a Database Transaction.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT                            
id,status,server
FROM
table_log
WHERE
(direction = '2' AND status_log = '1')
LIMIT 100
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

**what are we doing?**

We are Selecting all rows available (not locked) from other cron-jobs that might be running. And selecting them for update. So this means all this Query grabs its unlocked and all results will be locked for this cron-job only.

**how to update my locked rows?**

Simple use a for loop on your processor language (Python, Ruby, PHP) and do a concatenation for each update remember we are building 1 single update.

```
UPDATE table_log SET status_log = '6' ,server = '1' WHERE id = '1';
```

Finally we use

```
COMMIT;
```

And all rows locked will be updated. This prevents other Queries from touching the same data at the same time. Hope it helps.